# gdb "During startup program exited with code 126."

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a c++ program:

```
gdb simplesearch.o
```

Then gdb startups successfully:

```
(gdb) Reading symbols from /home/zwx/workspace/xapian/examples/simplesearch.o...done.
```

But when I tried to run:

```
(gdb) run
```

gdb reports:

```
Starting program: /home/zwx/workspace/xapian/examples/simplesearch.o 
/bin/bash: /home/zwx/workspace/xapian/examples/simplesearch.o: cannot execute binary file
/bin/bash: /home/zwx/workspace/xapian/examples/simplesearch.o: Success
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

Someone has idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `.o` file is not a program, it is an object file that needs to be linked with libraries to produce a program.  You can use `gdb` to inspect code within it, but it is not runnable (the "cannot execute binary file" message).  You will need to link it to make a program.  Possibly something like

```
g++ -o simplesearch simplesearch.o
```

will suffice, but without more information it's not clear if it needs more libraries than just the system C libraries and C++ runtime support, etc.

Comment: Yes. When I try to run `gdb simplesearch` (simplesearch is an executable file that can run as ./simplesearch). Then gdb reports: ""/home/zwx/workspace/xapian/examples/simplesearch": not in executable format: File format not recognized." @geekosaur

Comment: What does `file simplesearch` report?

Comment: still ""/home/zwx/workspace/xapian/examples/simplesearch": not in executable format: File format not recognized."

Comment: I think you did not understand what I asked.  At a shell prompt, type "file simplesearch".  It will not say anything about "not in executable format", because it is not trying to execute it.

Comment: I first type `gdb'`, then in gdb prompt, I type `file simplesearch`. It gave the above message. In the shell prompt when I type `file simplesearch`, It gives "simplesearch: Bourne-Again shell script text executable".

Comment: `gdb` will not work to debug shell scripts.  You need to find out how the object file is to be used, possibly by reading the shell script to see what it does.

Comment: Many thanks for your insightful answer. What about an ELF 64-bit LSB executable? Do I need to complite it as well (full output of file: `ELF 64-bit LSB, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`

Answer (score 0):

I tried chmod +x  it didn't work , than u used ChatGPT and gave me two options.
Make a "sestatus " ( i had to install it )
then went with " gdb sudo " and then hit the command " run " and worked perfectly